# How do I fix these broken cables/pins?

Tags: pcb, connector, wiring

I have this Infra-red USB receptor with 2 broken wires, marked in the picture with circles.

1. What type of connector/pin are these? Both connectors are similiar, except in size. Looks like they are soldered to the pcb.
2. How do I fix this?
3. Can I replace this type of connection with a stronger one,
   maybe something like a JST connector?

[image: How do I fix this]

[image]

Comment: unplug the large connector .... slightly lift the rectangular tab in the blue ellipse and pull out the metal contact .... figure out a way to reattach it to the wire ..... the small connector may need the same procedure to repair ....... add pictures of the contact if you are unsure of how to attach wire

Comment: How do I unplug the connectors? they seem to be soldered to the pcb

Comment: my bad .... the shell may possibly come off if you lift all 5 tabs slightly and slide the shell towards the small connector ... lift up on the tab and use a piece of paper as a shim to keep it lifted

Comment: That's not a removable connector. Only the crimped wires could come out.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the connector but that's unneeded. Youd have to get crimps for the wire and then unlatch the existing crimps and plug the new crimp in.

Just Remove the small connector cn2 (desolder) and just solder the wires to the board.

The bigger connector is more problematic as the leads are short. You could solder an extension that red wire and then solder the other end to the underside of the board, or trace it out and find another solder point. Make sure you use heatshrink to prevent a short.